# com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden - YouTube Live

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am new to YouTube APIs. I have done create and fetch live events on YouTube. But I'm trying to start live events from my app I'm getting this error:

```
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/transition?broadcastStatus=live&id=m0BCwKmG9Ws&key=AIzaSyCRiIM7Tdb_rqFcGSbQ0jXy0GeODCNSq4g&part=status
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
      "message": "Stream is inactive",
      "reason": "errorStreamInactive",
      "extendedHelp": "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Stream is inactive"
}
```

**Code for go-live**

```
fun startEvent(youtube: YouTube, broadcastId: String?) {
   
    val transitionRequest = youtube.liveBroadcasts().transition(
        "live", broadcastId, "status"
    )
    transitionRequest.key = context.getString(R.string.api_key)
    transitionRequest.execute()
}
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28803880/10875441) but still getting the same issue.
I don't know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will be resolved by enabling autostart while creating a live event

```
val contentDetails = LiveBroadcastContentDetails()
contentDetails.set("enableAutoStart", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the official specification of the [`LiveBroadcasts.transition`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition) API endpoint:

> Before calling this method, you should confirm that the value of the [`status.streamStatus`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#status.streamStatus) property for the stream bound to your broadcast is `active`.

The [error specification](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition#errors) reads as follows:

> **`forbidden (403)`** **`errorStreamInactive`**
> The requested transition is not allowed when the stream that is bound to the broadcast is inactive.

Hence, unequivocally, your live stream that's bound to your live broadcast must be active prior to invoking `LiveBroadcasts.transition`.

Comment: please tell me how to changes the live stream status from upcoming to active?

Comment: @Τζιότι: Your live stream becomes active once you -- as the initiator of the live broadcast -- start sending video content to the YouTube live stream's ingestion endpoint.

Comment: @Τζιότι: Note that your `status.streamStatus` cannot be `upcoming`: the [valid values of this property](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#status.streamStatus) are: `active`, `created`, `error`, `inactive` and `ready`.