# GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden- Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am new to YouTube APIs. I have done create and fetch live events on YouTube. But I'm trying to start live events from my app I'm getting error:

Code:

```
    fun startEvent(youtube: YouTube, broadcastId: String?) {
   
    val transitionRequest = youtube.liveBroadcasts().transition(
        "live", broadcastId, "status"
    )
    transitionRequest.key = context.getString(R.string.api_key)
    transitionRequest.execute()
}
```

Error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/transition?broadcastStatus=live&id=[BROADCAST_ID]&key=[API_KEY]&part=status
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
      "message": "Invalid transition",
      "reason": "invalidTransition",
      "extendedHelp": "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition#params"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid transition"
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318585/youtube-api-com-google-api-client-googleapis-json-googlejsonresponseexception/29620560

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I have already done that but still getting same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35083880/1841839

Comment: @DaImTo Done that but still not working